# How to call a method in a child (or any other) component after an event in the parent?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3

A question like this:
How is it possible in `vue3` after an event to call a method in another component?
Found this solution for vue2
`this.$refs.myComponent.myMethod()`
But how is it supposed to work without "this" in vue3 + composition api?

If this is not possible then what are the alternatives?
The event itself occurs in the following code:
(for example, we can take the resize event of a component and set a task - after it, activate a method inside another component)

```
 <Vue3DraggableResizable class="chartApp"
     @resizing="print('resizing')"
   >
```

How is it possible to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about if they are best practices but here we go.

1. I think you can watch your props change and trigger an event like this

   ```
   import { watch, toRefs } from 'vue'

   const props = defineProps({
      yourReactiveProp: Boolean
   })
   const { yourReactiveProp } = toRefs(props) // this is reactive

   watch(
     () => yourReactivePropn.value,
         (newVal) => {
            yourMethod() // you can pass the new value also.
   })
   ```
2. You can use [mitt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mitt) package. Literally, you can listen and fire emit from anywhere to anywhere. I.e, parent-child, child-parent, siblings, non-siblings, etc..